# Modularized Event Handling

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I have an application which is modularized. Each module is a separate project within the solution and the modules cannot reference one another. I'd like to add a system where a module can subscribe to events from the other modules.

For example say I have a Blogs module and a Menus module. When I delete a post in the Blogs module I'd like to also delete the corresponding menu item in the Menus module.

I'd appreciate it if you could help. Please let me know if you need more information as I'll be happy to provide it. Thanks

Comment: is there a database at some level? you could create a repository with an event system. (Though I'm not sure, after what you've said, why one module is dependent on another)

Comment: what .Net version do you use?

Comment: @Vasiliy: version 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your modules post their events to a global event queue of some sort. The event messages in that queue should have some tag indicating the module from which the event originated.

Any module that is interested in another module's events can then subscribe to a global events distributor, from where it will either receive

- all events, whereupon it has to filter itself based on the tag, or
- just events from a limited set of modules, whose IDs had to be passed upon subscription to the global events distributor.

Comment: Thanks but could you provide some sample code. This is abit new to me. Would you recommend using Prism as @mot suggested or should I roll my own solution?

Comment: @nfplee: No, sorry, I think your question is too broad to provide some specific sample code. This is nothing that could be solved in just two lines of code, or at least there would be much variation possible . As for Prism, I had never heard about it so far, so I can't tell.

Comment: Ok thanks. Will do some further research and see which solution looks best.

Comment: I have accepted this answer since I adapted the following http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2011/07/28/loosely-coupled-events-in-net-and-harvesting-open-source-projects/ using your instructions and it seems to working nicely. I looked at Prism but it appears tied to Silverlight and WPF.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use Prism's [EventAggreator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx), it fits your scenario perfectly.

Comment: Thanks this looks promising. I've had a quick read but looks like i'll have to do a little more research before I can understand how this will work for my application.

Comment: or just MEF based solution